# Writing a simple log from JSP/Servlet to UNIX/Shellscript

Tags: java, bash, unix, servlets, logging

I'm creating a simple log file, that will contains date/time and the user responsable of a determinated action. what I'm doing is the same thing that I usually do when I want to run a Shelscript (i.e. shellscript.sh) from a java Servlet:

```
ProcessBuilder pl = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/bash", "-c", "echo ($date) \" - Action_Name - " + User + "\" >> " + "myDirectory/logs/myLog.log");
pl.start();
```

I'm using this 2 commands alone, but after executing them, I couldn't see anything inside `myDirectory/logs/myLog.log`.

Why this code is not working?

Comment: Why don't you just open the file with a FileWriter and write to it directly?

Comment: You are 100% right, I was just curious to write a file THAT way.

Comment: The mind boggles as to why you would do this. There are many, many java logging frameworks out there; log4j being pretty ubiquitous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you accidentally specified `($date)` when you meant `$(date)`, so bash complained of a syntax error and didn't execute the command. You want this:

```
ProcessBuilder pl = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $(date) \" - Action_Name - " + User + "\" >> " + "myDirectory/logs/myLog.log");
pl.start();
```

If you checked the process return code or printed its error output you could see the failure. If you want to programmatically determine if the command fails, check the return code.

But like Qwerky mentioned in the comments, the mind does indeed boggle.